# What is the shortcut for attribute node? In Cycles Render, also.. (see below)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, shaders

I need to know the call shortcut for the attribute node in cycles render please :)[image]

I don't see the property box that one of the people answered...
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are in the node editor,use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to add a new node, followed by <kbd>I</kbd> then <kbd>A</kbd> (*Add>input>attribute*).

From the *properties panel* you will add it under the *normal* rollout of your material.

[image]

Comment: How do I get to the node editor?? I am new to Blender.

Comment: Never mind, I found it :)

Comment: @GabbyQuattrone If you find an answer solves your question, you can mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the 'tick' icon next to it. See: http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers